# SVG use and gradients as fill

Tags: html, svg, svg-sprite

I've been trying to externalize my SVG icons to a file and referencing them with markup like `<svg><use xlink:href="file.svg#icon" /></svg>`. In theory this works really nicely, but different browsers have issues with rendering. All the browsers are able to render the svg correctly when referencing the symbol with `<use>` inside the file and opening the svg file's url directly.

In short, is there a cross-browser way to get SVG `linearGradient`s working as fills for elements when referencing the symbols with `<svg><use/></svg>` in the markup?

I set up a plunker demonstrating the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/feKvZ7?p=preview

Simplified, the markup is like the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>SVG sprite test</h1>
        <svg width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <use xlink:href="icon.svg#icon" />
        </svg>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And the SVG file looks like this:

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="black" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      </symbol>
    
      <use id="iconuse" xlink:href="#icon" width="100" height="100" />
    
    </svg>
```

This is what it looks like in the different browsers:
[image: Different results of rendering linear gradients for symbols in different browser]

Comment: It's many years later... what do you do these days?

Comment: @NickDarvey a good question. I have abandoned using this approach and are nowadays using stuff like svgr: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr. Might be an interesting time to revisit, though. Giving a quick look at the Plunkr, there are still differences between browsers in how they render the different SVGs.

Answer (score 1):

The `symbol` tag is used to hide the elements that are inside it.  Elements inside the `symbol` are called using the `<use>` command by their unique indicator.
Therefore, it is better to use this method of calling individual elements rather than calling the whole `symbol`

In addition, elements when using `<use>` fall into the `shadow DOM` and using CSS in some cases becomes impossible
Therefore, it is better to delete all internal styles inside symbol and assign them directly to the `use` command

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <symbol  id="icon"  viewBox="0 0 100 100"> 
    <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"   />
     <rect id="rect" x="100" y="10" width="100" height="100" />
  </symbol>

  <use class="iconuse" xlink:href="#circle" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)" stroke="black" />
     <use class="iconuse" xlink:href="#rect" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: MDN shows using `xlink:href` directly for the symbol tag and not the individual elements inside it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol

Comment: @RJo Where is it said that you cannot call individual elements from Symbol? in MDN just an example with one inner element I have with two elements If you are sure of what you claim show the link from the spec W3C

Comment: That was just pointing to your original description: "it is better to use this method of calling individual elements rather than calling the whole symbol". Any way, the original question was about pointing to an element with an id inside an external SVG file. Not pointing to elements inside an inline SVG definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try next one (it's how Inkscape provide implementation of gradients):

```
<linearGradient id="gradient">
  <stop
     style="stop-color:black;"
     offset="0"/>
  <stop
     style="stop-color:white;"
     offset="1" />
</linearGradient>
...
<path
   style="fill:url(#gradient); ...
```

Comment: Changing the properties to be in `style` attributes did not fix the issue

Comment: Try to change inline SVG to img `<img src="./icon.svg#icon" />`

Comment: That would probably work for rendering, but I'll lose versatility. Wouldn't  want to go this way.

Comment: Any progress on this? I've run into the same issue and can't solve it.